# If $S_\epsilon$ is dense for all $\epsilon$, is $S_0$ dense?

Tags: real-analysis

*There is still a large part to be answered.*

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function, and $S_\epsilon=\{x: f(x) \le \epsilon\}$. Let $S_\epsilon$ be dense in $[0,1]$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Does it follow that $S_0$ is dense in $[0,1]$?

Initially I cared about when $f$ is Riemann integrable, but I have considered the following variants:

How does it affect the problem if $f$ is Riemann integrable, or continuous?

For what sort of sets $A,B$ does it hold if we replace $[0,1], \mathbb{R}$ with $A,B$?

---

Clearly the last question will have a dependency on whether $f$ is restricted to be Riemann integrable, or indeed continuous.

The continuous case is perhaps trivial, if it is I will be happy to edit it out.

Comment: This is definitely true when $f$ is continuous; I don't see a trivial proof though.

Comment: Baire, measures or whatever are fine to use, this isn't a homework, but I doubt they will be that useful here, even if it feels a little Bairey.

Comment: It certainly helps

Comment: The italics are directed not at anyone who has already answered, but at potential answerers.

Comment: I think being a Baire space is the exact condition of $A$ and $B$ to hold this when $f$ is continuous.

Edited:There was a little typo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For general functions the answer is no: let $f(\frac{p}{q})=\frac{1}{q}$ where $p,q$ form a reduced fraction, and $f(x) = 1$, where $x$ is irrational - this is almost the [popcorn function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). Clearly $S_0=\emptyset$ but $S_\epsilon$ contains all irreducible fractions $p/q$ with large $q$.

---

For continuous functions the answer is yes: $S_\epsilon$ is dense (by assumption) and closed (because $f$ is continuous), therefore $S_\epsilon = [0,1]$ for any $\epsilon>0$, and $S_0 = \bigcap S_\epsilon = [0,1]$.

Comment: Wow, the popcorn function is a nice monster :).

Answer (score 3):

For a Riemann integrable function $f$ the answer is yes, with an argument which is a generalization of the one already given by sdcvvc for continuous $f$.

Let $f$ be a Riemann integrable function on $[0,1]$. By the [Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability), $f$ must be bounded and continuous almost everywhere: the set of its points of discontinuity has measure zero, in the sense of Lebesgue measure. Let $C$ and $D$ denote the set of points of continuity, respectively discontinuity for $f$ on $[0,1]$, then $D=[0,1]\setminus C$, and $D$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. This implies that $C$ is dense in $[0,1]$ (for otherwise $D$ must contain an open interval and hence would have positive Lebesgue measure, a contradiction), so it would be enough to show that $f(x)\le0$ for each $x\in C$, that is $C\subseteq S_0$.

Fix $x\in C$. Since each $S_\epsilon$ is dense, we could pick a point $a_n\in S_{\frac1n}\cap(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n)$. Then clearly $a_n\to x$ and $f(a_n)\le\frac1n$ and since $f$ is continuous at $x$ we have $f(a_n)\to f(x)$. But $\lim_n f(a_n) \le \lim_n \frac1n = 0$, 
concluding that $f(x)\le 0$, so $x\in S_0$.

Comment: There is a generalization to this. Consider a Baire Space $X$ with a finite Borel measure $\mu$ which takes on strictly positive values on open sets. If a function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous $\mu$-almost everywhere, then the denseness of the $S_{\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon>0$ imply the denseness of $S_0$.